# I can't uninstall Windows 7 from a laptop. Can I reuse the COA?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

My laptop has a really small harddrive. It says that I can't uninstall Windows 7 because there isn't enough space. Can I reuse the Windows 7 key on my new laptop?

Comment: Uninstall? Did you mean you want to reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Click Start, type: CMD
Right click CMD
Click Run as administrator
At the command prompt, type: slmgr.vbs -upk

Hit Enter, this will uninstall the product key from the computer and set it back to trial mode, you are now free to use it on another computer. If you encounter any problems, try activating by telephone: